# Vim matches a rectangle area

Tags: regex, vim

I want to match a rectangle area in Vim using a regex expression, for example:

```
abcd test1
abcd test2
```

I want to match `test1` and `test2` at once, but not `abcd`s.
(`test1` and `test2` are constant, we don't need to consider `[0-9]`, that's just an example)

I want to match every column-aligned `test1` `test2`

This

```
test1
test2
```

the rectangle area may appear anywhere, I can't assume it is at "column 3" or something of that sort.

If they are not aligned, don't match it.

I tried `\1\@<=test1\n\(.*\)\@<=test2` but no luck, because lookahead breaks a group. (from `:help \\@<=`)

Does anyone know how to do it with only vim-regex? Thanks.

---

Edit:

A complicated example may be this one:

```
aaaaaaaaa
b test1 b
c test2 c
ddddddddd
```

match only `test1` and `test2`.

Usin two or more regex is acceptable (one for `test1` and the other for `test2`?)

---

Edit2:

This is just for fun, I am just curious about how much vim can achieve, it's not a serious problem, it may be boring and meaningless for many people and that is fine with me, please don't be bothered, good night :)

Comment: You *might* be able to do a block selection and search on that. I know for sure you can do `<c-v>`, select your region and `:s/test/soemthing`, for example.

Comment: Besides, why I can't start my question with ``Hello, stackoverflow``? I just want to say hello to this good site...

Comment: @WayneWerner: ``<C-v>`` is awesome, but I want to match it in my syntax file.

Comment: SO is a Q&A site - anything more or less than that belongs in the chat. Those of us who are here know it's a great site ;)

Comment: So... you want your syntax file to highlight test1 when test2 is on the line immediately below it? That seems pretty complicated - it might be better suited for vimscript/plugin

Comment: @WayneWerner: Yes that's I want :D
Currently I just matched ``^test1\ntest2$``, only "no spaces before them" case. :(

Comment: What is the end goal? Why are you trying to match a rectangular area? What are you going to do with this text?

Comment: @PeterRincker: Just for fun, I add some keyword like ``Google``, ``twitter`` in my syntax file, so when I type ``Google``, vim automatically color it with "Blue Red Yellow Blue Green Red".
Now I want to add a square pattern into it but don't know how.

Comment: What do you mean by column aligned ? Visually, or literally ? Visually, it would be the number of delimiters. Literally it is the column number. You can do this by using a constant regex for `test1` then using the match results to construct `test2`. Literal example" `^(.*?)test1`, then compose `^.{length of capture group1}test2`

Comment: @Cychih I don't see how are square pattern and `Google` even `hi` related.

Comment: @sln: I think I want visually (not sure if I understanded wrong), I want to match them if their starting column are the same (don't need to consider Chinese characters which have multiple bytes.)
But that solution needs two step to achieve, may not be done in static syntax file :(

Comment: @Kent: I already have a ``hi`` for ``Google`` literal and many others, but all of them are only a "word", I don't know how to color logos like "UNI\nQLO", which is a rectangle.

Comment: I doesn't matter about Unicode. The dot `.` metachar in regex is in character semantics, not byte  semantics.

Comment: I don't think this can be done purely with regex, but it probably can be done with some `normal` magic.

Comment: Do you want to *match* a rectangular area? Or *highlight* it? There is a big difference, since a match needs to be one sequential blob of text, but you can highlight just about anything.

Comment: Now I realize regex engines are not restricted to regular languages but this seems an awful lot like `a^nb^ma^nb^m` problem which is strictly not regular. I imagine if you could "capture" the column (`\%c`) or virtual column (`\%v`) and then *somehow* use that value in the rest of the regex then such a regex could exist. Personally I think you would have to find the rectangle yourself then calculate the column so you could build such a regex. Even after that you would need to build use both look-aheads and look-behinds to make sure the rectangle was contiguous (read slow).

Comment: Example match that will work for your second example: `\v%(%(%3c\S{4}%7c\S\s.*\n.*\s)@<=%3c\S{4}%7c\S|%3c\S{4}%7c\S%(\s.*\n.*\s%3c\S{4}%7c\S)@=)` Note: this requires you know the column positions so the regex can be crafted.

Comment: @Ben: I want to highlight it in my syntax file :D

Comment: @sln: Yes, ``abctest1\n測ctest2`` may fail, because the ``測`` is a double widthed character but ``.`` match it as only one character.

Comment: @PeterRincker: WOW the regex is so long, I can't write constant column in it, but thanks anyway, I found many interesting operators in that regex :3

Comment: @PeterRincker: The ``test1`` and ``test2`` can be constant

Comment: Don't know if it helps, but check `:help \%v` and see if it helps. I use this together with `:vimsort` to sort lines on a specific column.

Comment: @Vitor: thank you, I'll take a look after all my final exams finished :D

Answer (score 1):

Simply searching for `/test[0-9`] will suffice. But I think the spirit of the question is really more about visual blocks. In visual mode you can use text objects for movement. So, in this case:

1. Search for test1.
2. Press Control-V (to turn on visual block mode)
3. Press `w` to visually select the entire word.
4. Press `j` to visually select the next word in the column below the first one. (use a range to extend this rectangular block, e.g. `10j` would visually select the next ten items in that column.)

Comment: Hi gregory, it's not about visual block. What I wanted was to (syntax) highlight a pattern that expands to multiple lines.

Comment: um, highlighting search results is visual; and highlighting multiple lines is a visual block. Syntax highlighting is something else, based on a language template (e.g :syntax include @CPP syntax/cpp.vim) which you can turn on and off  to highlight pieces of code -- perhaps that's what your looking for?

Comment: Yes, I was looking for "syntax" highlighting, so I can color a piece of text with complex color combinations.

Comment: For example, [my vim setting](https://github.com/pi314/rcfiles/blob/master/.vim/syntax/todo.vim#L38) highlights keyword "Google" with [blue, red, yellow, blue, green, red].
Just for fun anyway, don't be too serious :D

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to find the match you need 
The syntax is 
`/somethingWeAreLooking\(_.\)*followedByTheOtherThing`

In this case it will be like this:

`/test\(_.\)*[1-9]`

Comment: What is ``_.``? I only find ``\_.`` in ``:help``, which is "any single char or EOL".
The regex's behavior looks like ``test[1-9]``, it matches the pattern even if ``test1`` and ``test2`` are not aligned at same column :(

Comment: IMHO: The `_` aka underscore does these: Matches a comma (,), left brace ({), right brace (}), left parenthesis ( ( ), right parenthesis ( ) ), the beginning of the string, the end of the string, or a space : In this case `_.` It concatenates the end of a string matching a digit btn 1-9

Comment: @abdimuna `_.` is nothing special, just two characters in a grouping which never gets back referenced. In your simple search, test[1-9] works. Alternatively, if your search wanted to include underscores and periods (e.g. test_3) you could use this regex or its equivalent: test[_.]*[0-9]. (see http://vimregex.com for more details.)